# One "if" conditional evaluating to true causes next if-statement to evaluate to true

Tags: c++, if-statement, cout

When the first if-statement of the code below evaluates to true, strangely the second if-statement also evaluates to true. Even more strangely, the second if-statement DOES NOT evaluate to true (as should be the case) if I comment out the `cout` line in the first statement.

When the `cout` is not commented out and the first conditional evaluates to true, I get some very weird values for `cities[202].getNext()->getX()`, which is printed out in the second if-statement code block.

Btw, this code is just performing some unit tests, hence the hard coded values. In the first if-statement, `cities[202].getID()` should == 202, so that the if-statement evaluates to false. However, I'm testing my testing code, so I changed `cities[202].getID() != 202` to `cities[202].getID() != 201`

```
// test middle element of vect
    if( cities[202].getID() != 201 /*should be 202, wrote 201 on purpose*/ || cities[202].getX() != 188 || cities[202].getY() != 41){
        pass = 0;
         // second conditional below fails (which is good) if I do not comment out this next line with cout
        cout << "error with middle city x, y or id" << endl;
    }
        // middle element's next and prev should point to Default obj, with id=777, x=77, y=7 
    if( cities[202].getNext()->getX() != 77 || cities[202].getNext()->getID() != 777){
        pass = 0;
        cout << "error with middle city next" << endl;
        cout << "cities[202].getNext->getX = " << cities[202].getNext()->getX() << endl;
    }
```

Any ideas of the reasons for such an occurence? How could a `cout` possibly cause something like this?

Comment: First of all that cout statement has nothing to do with the execution of next if block.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, there is no reason that it should affect the next if block. Thus I'm quite puzzled at the moment.

Comment: Here's my guess: the pointer returned by `getNext()` is dangling and pointed to something that used to exist on the stack. The function calls made by the output statement used the stack so whatever used to be there got overwritten.

Comment: I think you are right, sir. I think the dangling pointer and fact that the function calls used the stack is indeed the root of the problem. Currently investigating. Thanks!

Comment: That was indeed the case! Thanks again for the intuition and phenomenal explanation on the root of the problem, hit the nail on the head.